# Filling entity in model binder vs external method that replace binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have asp.net MVC web application. It is the list of some entities where a user could pick up some of them and views details and so on.

Most of the actions of this application have some `Entity` as a parameter. For example:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Details(Entity entity)
{
    ...
    return View();
}
```

I keep this entity in session and fill this parameter in the model binder by id from URL. It looks like:

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var httpContext = controllerContext.HttpContext;
    var values = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;

    if (!values.ContainsKey("id")) return null;

    var id = values["id"].ToString();
    var obj = httpContext.Session["Entities"];
    var list =  (List<Entity>) obj;
    return list?.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

But time to time it is possible case that the user tries to access to action when session object is empty. For example, a user gets URL by email to action and omits code that puts Entity in session.

What is the best fix for this case?

**1. Implement getting entity in the binder:**

```
    var id = values["id"].ToString();
    var obj = httpContext.Session["Entities"];
    var list =  (List<Entity>) obj;
    var entity = list?.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    if(null==entity){
        entity = repository.GetEntity(id);
        //set entity in session
    }

    return entity;
```

This way looks nasty because of I have to implement extra filling logic in the binder. Also, I can't inject repository in the binder. But this way is simple and easy to implement.

**2. Remove the binder and add some get method:**

Remove binder at all and change all action with Entity in the next way:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Details()
{
    Entity entity = GetEntity();
    ...
    return View();
}
private Entity GetEntity()
{
    var id = ... //get id from http request.
    var list = (List<Entity>)Session["Entities"];
    var entity = list?.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

    if(null==entity){
        entity = repository.GetEntity(id);
        //set entity in session
    }

    return entity; 
}
```

I can implement injection of repository now, the code is safe but looks ugly.

Which solution is best? Is it possible that I have missed any another implementation?

Comment: Why do you think Option 2 looks ugly? Its the normal approach, and a ModelBinder should not be call your repository (and you method should have a parameter for the `id`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Good point about 'id'. It is the normal approach but it doesn't look elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This way looks nasty because of I have to implement extra filling
>   logic in the binder. Also, I can't inject repository in the binder.

You are correct that dependency injection cannot be properly done in a model binder. But you could use a factory:

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private readonly Func<IRepository> repositoryProvider;

    public MyModelBinder(Func<IRepository> repositoryProvider)
    {
        this.repositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;
    }

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var id = ... //get id from http request.
        var list = (List<Entity>)Session["Entities"];
        var entity = list?.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        if (null == entity)
        {
            IRepository repository = this.repositoryProvider();
            entity = repository.GetEntity(id);
            //set entity in session
        }

        return entity; 
    }
}
```

and then when registering your binder:

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(Entity)] = new MyModelBinder(
    () => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRepository>()
);
```